# Summing results from one function in other function Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have 2 functions. In one i get the results that I want, and with other function, I want to get sum of those results. 
I'm trying to call the first function i second function, but it does not work.
My idea was to append all values that I got with first function in the list, and then to sum that list in the second function.

This is the code:

```
    def cost_size_all():

    c.execute("""SELECT project_size, project_costs FROM projects""")
    connection.commit()
    project_list = c.fetchall()

    cost_size_list = []

    i=0
    for project in project_list:
        i +=1
        avrage = round(project[1] / project[0], 2)
        print(i,")",avrage)
        cost_size_list.append(avrage)

        connection.commit()

avrage_costs = cost_size_all()


def avrage_cost_size():

    x = cost_size_all().cost_size_list
    print(x)


a = avrage_cost_size()

connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a return in the function cost_size_all, otherwise you can't use the result.

Here is one solution :

```
def cost_size_all():

avrage_list = []

c.execute("""SELECT project_size, project_costs FROM projects""")
connection.commit()
project_list = c.fetchall()

i=0
for project in project_list:
    i +=1
    avrage = round(project[1] / project[0], 2)
    print(i,")",avrage)
    connection.commit()
    avrage_list.append(avrage)

return avrage_list;


def avrage_cost_size():

    cost_size_list = cost_size_all()

    print(sum(cost_size_list))



avrage_cost_size()
```

Tell me if it worked for you

SLP

Comment: Sorry but no, because calling     (cost_size_list = cost_size_all() ) will print me all what (cost_size_all()) does , plus list that I want.
I want to find a way to call only list.